# Using symlinks stored in /usr/bin that point to other folders to have them in path

Tags: symbolic-link, paths

I have a python script (which requires several other python files) in a folder, `~/Desktop/ufonet`.

I thought that by making a symlink (I tried both hard and soft) to that folder it would put it in my path.

It didn't work, so I tried making the symlink to the executable.

It worked, but the program inherited the `/usr/bin` cwd, so it could not find its dependencies.

What is the correct way to do it without passing the cwd?

Comment: @Zanna Sorry, somehow I managed to screw up... it did work after pointing it to the executable, but it "inherited" the current working directory, for that very reason it can't find it's dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a simple wrapper script.

If the program is for your use only and you wish to keep it in `~/Desktop/ufonet`, then create an executable script

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME/Desktop/ufonet && ./yourscript
```

and place it in `~/bin`, which is added to your `PATH` by the default Ubuntu `~/.profile`.

If you want to make the program available to other users, do essentially the same thing but place the wrapper in `/usr/local/bin`. In that case, I'd suggest moving the whole `ufonet` directory to `/usr/local` as well, so that the wrapper becomes

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/local/ufonet && ./yourscript
```